# Let's have our own Twitter account?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Would it be good if we have our own twitter account which is a bot which regularly tweets interesting questions.

As our daily visitor stat is improving really good since some time now, I think having a twitter account would improve that even further, especially as the site is getting active day by day and is constantly getting good quality questions (of course, with help of really nice moderation from the users.)

[I'm not sure how a twitter account gets created. Maybe, the mods need to submit a proposal.] [Unrelated, but a helpful Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92235/302377)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to assume people who want to see DS questions from this StackExchange will follow it directly and get email updates tailored to their interests. I don't know if it adds a lot of value to maintain a Twitter account. That said I don't object to someone doing so.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. However, for people who don't know about the site, can be fished in through the twitter account, as it uses hashtags which are the tags of the question (and our hashtags like `hadoop`, `spark`, `XGBoost` are widely followed on Twitter). So, we get more (and) nice answers, and more people would get to know about the site!  Win-Win  :)